# Is it possible to control the height of the Portfolio panel via iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am using *iTextSharp* to assemble a couple of PDF files into a PDF Portfolio.

Is it possible to set on the created PDF Portfolio a directive to *Adobe Acrobat Reader* what should be the height of the *Portfolio* panel (red line on the image below)?

[image]

The idea, basically, is to adjust the height of the panel to the number of files in the portfolio.

Alternatively, is there a way to set on the created PDF Portfolio a directive to open by default the *Layout* pane instead of the *Files* pane?

Thank you all in advance for assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked [a similar question at the *Adobe* Forums](http://forums.adobe.com/message/6009329), and the *Adobe* answer is:
No, there is no PDF directive that one can embed into a PDF Portfolio and control the height of the *Portfolio* panel.